# PrincipalName cannot be empty error in oauth2

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I have integrated Oauth2.0 implementation for social sign flows, I am trying to login the user via facebook, I have used scope as email. I am getting issues when the facebook account is registered via phone number and there is no basic information. The error is occurring on Oauth2LoginAuthenticationFilter class, where we have assert statements to validate the principal name.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: principalName cannot be empty
org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284)
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient.(OAuth2AuthorizedClient.java:72)
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat logs.

Could you please help me on how to handle this exception.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this exception occurred when there was no "sub" claim in JWT payload.

In this [article](https://tipsfordev.com/spring-security-5-with-oauth2-causing-principalname-cannot-be-empty-error) shown how to fix this issue.

Comment: The link is to an non-existing site